# Upload and Loading videos in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I has being develop video uploading app using react-native.User can record video by in app camera.

Are there any way to reduce file size and/or uploading time also displaying/loading time in react-native or javascript? Are there any help to solve this one in front-end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can optimize file size and also display upload progress. FFmpeg is generally used to manipulate video files. With the help of WebAssembly, you can execute FFMpeg right within the app and manipulate video files. Refer to the GitHub [link](https://github.com/BrianJFeldman/ffmpeg.js.wasm). [You may have to check if this works with React native]

The idea is to read the blob received from MediaRecorder (available in chrome and firefox, there is also npm package for react native) and pass it to FFMpeg WebAssembly port. Later the optimized bytes can be sliced using Blob and sent to the server (check the slice method in JavaScript Blob).

**Recommendation**
While you can perform all the above steps right within the client app, it is better to run video optimization utilities in the server rather than within the client app. The right approach to stream the data received from MediaRecorder at regular intervals to the server using either WebSocket or Ajax requests.

Comment: Thank you @CuriousMind. When handling optimization in back-end can I reduce the uploading time?

Comment: The uploading time will depend on multiple parameters - The audio/video bitrate, width and height of video, framerate, user network speed etc. As said earlier, the better option is to stream the bytes at regular intervals instead of uploading entire data at one go.